# Blazor & gRPC routing

Tags: blazor, grpc, .net-5

This was working a few months ago before I upgraded to .net 5.0.

On a Blazor page, using gRPC, I call my Ping("wee") which should return a string. Instead it gives the following ouput:

```
dbug: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[1]
      Starting gRPC call. Method type: 'Unary', URI: 'https://localhost:44395/MyGrpc.GrpcWebService/Ping'.
dbug: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[18]
      Sending message.
trce: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[21]
      Serialized 'System.String' to 5 byte message.
trce: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[19]
      Message sent.
trce: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[2]
      Response headers received.
info: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[3]
      Call failed with gRPC error status. Status code: 'Internal', Message: 'Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 400'.
dbug: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[4]
      Finished gRPC call.
```

Not exactly sure where to go from here...but if I paste the url `https://localhost:44395/MyGrpc.GrpcWebService/Ping` into the browser I get a Blazor page--not a gRPC encoded response.

Is there a conflict between gRPC and Blazor routing?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll answer my own question.  Turns out endpoint ordering matters.  You have to register your gRPC services

```
    app.UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<MyService>() |> ignore
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<WeatherService>() |> ignore
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<GrpcWebService>() |> ignore
    )
```

before standard blazor endpoints:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
```